# Neo4j Cypher, need an optimized way of getting friend of friend of friend who are not in a 1 or 2 degree connection

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to Neo4j and trying to get friends of friends of friends (those who are 3 degrees away) and are also not in a 1 or 2 degree relation through a different path.  I am using the below cypher which seems to take a lot of time

> MATCH p = (origin:User {ID:51})-[:LINKED*3..3]-(fof:User)
>
> WHERE NOT (origin)-[:LINKED*..2]-(fof)
>
> RETURN fof.Nm
>
> ORDER BY Nm LIMIT 1000

Profiling the query shows that the majority of time is taken by the "WHERE NOT" condition as it cross checks every resultant node against all the 1 and 2 degree nodes.

Am I doing something wrong here or is there a more optimized way of doing this?

Just to add, the property UsrID in label User is indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a few ways you could do it.  Here's one to try:

```
MATCH path = (origin:User {ID:51})-[:LINKED*3..3]-(fofof:User)
WHERE NOT(fofof IN (nodes(path)[0..-1]))
RETURN fofof.Nm
ORDER BY fofof.Nm LIMIT 1000
```

You could also be more explicit:

```
MATCH path = (origin:User {ID:51})-[:LINKED]-(f:User)-[:LINKED]-(fof:User)-[:LINKED]-(fofof:User)
WHERE fofof <> f AND fofof <> fof
RETURN fofof.Nm
ORDER BY fofof.Nm LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for the quick response, your suggested ways are definitely much faster, however can you also throw some light on how could I achieve the same if I had to look against 3 or more degrees away and ensure they are not 1 or 2 degree connected.  Wouldn't it be better to select against all nodes instead of traversing through an open ended path `*3..`? and in that case how will the condition work considering there is no defined path.

Comment: The first query should be expandable to any path length since it's just making sure that the last node in the path isn't one of the first through second-to-last nodes.  In an open-ended case you probably want the shortest path between the `origin` and the last node.  You can use Cypher's `shortestPath` and return `length(path)` at the end (`shortestPath`: http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-match.html )